# PHP variable to select option

Tags: php, forms

I have a php variable `$valuable='bottomValue'`

and a select drop down inside a form which upon submit returns to the same page

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<select>
<option value='topValue'>One</option>
<option value='midValue'>Two</option>
<option value='bottomValue'>Three</option>
</select>
<input name='theSubmit' type='submit' />
</form>
```

Based upon the value of the `$valuable` how can I change the selected option to match.

For example on page load because the default value of the variable = 'bottomValue' option three would be selected

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use other technology, javascript for example, you have to check the value for each option like this:

```
<option value='bottomValue' <?php echo ($valuable == 'bottomValue')?'selected':''; ?>>Three</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do smth like this:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<select>
<option value='topValue'>One</option>
<option value='midValue'>Two</option>
<option value='bottomValue' 
      <?php echo $valuable == 'bottomValue' ? 'selected' : '' ?>
      >Three</option>
</select>
<input name='theSubmit' type='submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first make Array of your values and then do this

```
$values = array (
1 => 'topValue',
2 => 'middleValue',
3=> 'bottomValue',
);
```

and then

```
 <form action='' method='post'>
           <select>                                                         


    foreach( $values as $name => $v)
    {
      if( $name == $valuable )
           {
    echo '<option'.' value="'.$v.'"'.' selected="selected"'.'>'.$v.'</option>';
            }
    else
        {
    echo '<option'.' value="'.$v.'"'.'>'.$v.'</option>';
            }
         }

  </select>
```

best thing abt this Method You dun need inline php code for eacchhh option:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$valueable = 'bottomValue';

// array of the options you want to display in your select dropdown
$options = array(
    'topValue' => 'One',
    'midValue' => 'Two',
    'bottomValue' => 'Three'
);

$html = '<form action='' method='post'>';
$html .= '<select>';
foreach($options as $value => $display){
    if($value == $valuable){
        $html .= '<option value="'.$value.'" selected>'.$display.'</option>';
    }else{
        $html .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$display.'</option>';
    }
}

$html .= '</select>';
$html .= '<input name="theSubmit" type="submit" />';
$html .= '</form>';

echo $html;
```